# Small exception in linking shared library

Tags: linux, monodevelop, ubuntu-12.04, awesomium

I have kept libawesomium.1.6.5.so and libawesomium.1.6.5.so.0 files in /usr/lib/awesomium.1.6.5 folder, and given the path for this .so library in ld.co.config.d, in a new .conf file, but when I run my project it gives me a

System.dll not found exception for libawesomium.1.6.5.so.0 at (wrapper managed-to-native).

How to solve this error.
when i check the existence of this library through

sudo ldconfig -p | grep libawesomium-1.6.5.so

command, it gives me the following output:

libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/awesomium-1.6.5/libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0

It means it exists. But still at run-time my project is giving this error :

System.dllnotfoundexception libawesomium-1.6.5.so.0

I am working on monodevelop, so can someone suggest me please what is the thing that i am missing. Is there some addon i have to install or some terminal command i have to follow. Hoping for quick responses.

Regards

Rohit

Comment: Did you run `sudo ldconfig -v` ?

Comment: yes sir i run this command its showing so many libraries..but i could not see libawesomium-1.6.5.so ... what's the issue sir?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add LIBDIR=/lib to /etc/ld.so.conf and then issue ldconfig. If not, then you might be using a VMX or other type of setup that would require to you use the linker with -W/lib for example.

Answer (score 0):

i have need 2 days to find a solution for this problem!
On Linux Wheezy 32bit you need to install libjpeg62 ...

apt-get install libjpeg62

this will fix the problem! ...